# ERD design for multiple same shaped table

Tags: sql, oracle, erd

[image: design]

Hello we are now working on international site design ,so many table need to have relation to the same shaped small translation table , which store translation for each langueges like left side of the image (Design#1).
Currently we have an idea to merge translation table like right side of the image (Design#2), but I'm not clear this design is good or bad. Could you tell me Design#2 is good or bad idea ?
Also if you have another solution for this case , please give me an advice.

Comment: The benefit from Design#2 is that it's easier to maintain the translations. Because you have a only one table where the translations are stored. 
Drawback that sometime in a different context the same word has a different translation. This is handled with the refId, so I think that Design#2 is the way I would design as well. Probably I would store the word in the original language in the "Translation" table as well.

Comment: Without knowing details it is not possible to say anything. IMO a suitable *check* for the acceptance of the desing 2 is the question: "If you wake up one morning a you see a *chair connected with a desk translation record* is it a big problem?" And trust me this will happen in desing 2 as *there is no database constraint* preventing it.